# setTimeout() in node.js wont take effect inside listener

Tags: node.js, while-loop, timer

Im trying to setup a simple server to poke a database every 5 seconds and fetch data from it.

I've built a dummy function called "check_pairs" just to make sure that the setTimeout function is working, but it doesn't seems to make the timeout, it just prints without delays[image]

any idea why is that? Im also importing the current imports and using node version `v19.6.0`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wait for the `setTimeout` promise to resolve. Try this:

```
async function check_pair() {
  while (true) {
    console.log("Checking pairs");
    await setTimeout(1000);
  }
}
```